# External disk drive no longer visible when using Parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop

My MacMini Late 2012 has a 1Tb external USB drive, which I use as the main data store (the internal 256Gb SSD being too small).

I have been running parallels on this Mac for years and both native Mac drives were visible... I think it listed each twice in Windows Explorer for some reason.

Just today I really need to access large (several GB) files but now the external drive is not visible (of course). I found this but it doesn't help: http://kb.parallels.com/en/118147

MacOS 10.10.5, Parallels 13.

Answer (score 1):

Take your drive to another computer and Cloud your files.

Comment: What does that mean, "Cloud your files?"  Please elaborate.